# Duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 in osx

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clang, clion

I use `clion` in `osx` to compile my c++ project using `clang`, but it complains about `duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64`, here is the detail message:

```
duplicate symbol __ZN4Util16axisAngle2rotMatERKN5Eigen6MatrixIdLi3ELi1ELi0ELi3ELi1EEEf in:
CMakeFiles/ahrs.dir/src/algs.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/ahrs.dir/src/AHRS.cpp.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
```

I search for a while and it seems that I might link the header file in wrong way, but I look through my cpp and I think I didn't do something wrong.

algs.cpp:

```
#include <algs.h>
#include <Util.h>
#include <AHRS.h>
```

AHRS.cpp:

```
#include <AHRS.h>
#include <Util.h>
```

algs.h:

```
#ifndef AHRS_ALGS_H
#define AHRS_ALGS_H
#include <Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
class algs {
  private:
   VectorXi stationary;
  public:
   VectorXd filter(MatrixX3d& acc);
   void gradient_descent(MatrixX3d acc, MatrixX3d gyo, VectorXi time);
};

#endif //AHRS_ALGS_H
```

Util.h:

```
#ifndef AHRS_UTIL_H
#define AHRS_UTIL_H

#include <math.h>
#include <Dense>
#include <src/Geometry/Quaternion.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace Eigen;

namespace Util {
    //many inline functions in this namespace.
    ...
}
#endif //AHRS_UTIL_H
```

AHRS.h:

```
#ifndef AHRS_AHRS_H
#define AHRS_AHRS_H
#include <Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
class AHRS {
 private:
  Quaterniond q;
  Vector3d int_error;
  int kp_ramped;

 public:
  double kp;
  int ki;
  int kp_init;
  int init_period;
  double sample_period;
  Quaterniond quaternion;

  AHRS();

  void reset();
};

#endif //AHRS_AHRS_H
```

and the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(AHRS)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

add_subdirectory(test)

include_directories(Eigen)
include_directories(include)

set(AHRS_HEAD include/)
set(AHRS_SRC src/main.cpp src/Biquad.cpp src/filtfilt.cpp src/Butterworth.cpp src/algs.cpp src/AHRS.cpp)

add_executable(ahrs ${AHRS_SRC} ${AHRS_HEAD})
```

all my header files is in the `include` folder. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `__ZN4Util16axisAngle2rotMatERKN5Eigen6MatrixIdLi3ELi1ELi0ELi3ELi1EEEf ` function `Util::axisAngle2rotMat(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const&, float)` isn't inlined

Comment: You should use 'static' for your inline functions to prevent the compiler making a global symbol in the case it cannot inline the function.

Comment: @PaulHK, no you don't. Specifying it as `inline` is enough. In fact, adding `static` may cause the executable to bloat in size, I think.

Comment: @Danh you are right, I make it inline and it runs well, but actually I don't even use it in other files. Why does the `inline` declaration make sense? By the way how do you know that '__ZN4Util16axisAngle2rotMatERKN5Eigen6MatrixIdLi3ELi1ELi0ELi‌​3ELi1EEEf' means the function is not inline?

Comment: You don't call it doesn't stop it from be compiled to the object file, in the linking step, it doesn't stop the linker from seeing 2 definition with the same name. You can search for cxx demangling. Either in the library libcxxabi or in the internet

Comment: @Danh Ok. I will search for that. Thanks.